# Would a set of tensors be an algebraic group closed under some operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors

Could a set of tensors be known as an algebraic group or why would that not have a group properties? The reason I'm asking is to understand different tensors.

Comment: Careful with the term "algebraic group."  It means something that I don't think you want it to mean here.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. What exactly do you mean by «tensors»? What is an algebraic group» to you?

Comment: According to Norman Biggs book discrete mathematics, a group could be a mathematical object with some operation and I think I remember an interesting example with a triangle with a rotation operation (or numbers with addition). Then I read about the kronecker delta and then I'm not sure whether we can write 2 tensors as 1 tensor of tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question to ask would be "a group under what operation?"  In any reasonable setting (say, for vector spaces $V$ and $W$, both over a field $K$), the space $V\otimes W$ is an $additive$ group, since it is closed under addition and additive inverses.  It is not in general, a $multiplicative$ group.  How would you even define $(v\otimes w) \cdot (x\otimes y)$?  What would be the multiplicative identity?  Would such a structure be closed under multiplicative inverses?

Given a vector space $V$, there is such a thing as the $tensor$ $algebra$ $T(V)$.  This is not a multiplicative group, but it does provide a framework for multiplying tensors, and contains a multiplicative identity.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra

Comment: Thank you for providing details. I thought there was a (conceptual) difference between how to make a statement about "all tensors" and "every tensor" since what's true for every tensor might not be true for "all tensors", which would be a set or some other way to write many tensors at once. I heard that a matrix of matrices could be a tensor, so could there be a tensor of tensors instead and therefore all tensors can be written as one tensor of tensors?

Comment: It depends on your definition of tensor.  What is a tensor?  Where do your tensors 'live'?  Any vector in any vector space could be considered a 'tensor'.

Comment: Can we write 2 tensors as 1 tensor of tensors (similar to how we can make a superset of 2 sets)? Could the basics of rotation, translation and scaling make a good example? If the 2 matrices are tensors, can I make a matrix of matrics and still keep it a tensor of 2 or more tensors? In an application we got 3 or more matrices but I have no proof why there must be no less than 3 matrices (rotation matrix, translation matrix and scaling matrix).

Comment: *the tensor algebra $T(V)$. This is not a group...* well, it is an additive group along with every other algebra over a field, but the multiplication does not make it a group... I guess this is what you mean...

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the correction.  I have included the work 'multiplicative'.